# Read last line of file after the file was modified

Tags: linux, bash, email, terminal, tail

I have a problem with reading the last line of file in Linux Ubuntu. 
I have a file named auth.log and I'm trying to read it last line after new line was added (after file was modified).
I know i need to use 
`tail -1 /var/log/auth.log` to get last line but I don't know how to check the file every time it was modified. 
After reading the last line i need to check if it contains "login" word and if yes I need to send this line by email. As far as I know grep needs to be use with mail command.

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work for you, using `tail -f` to continuously monitor the file:

```sh
while read -r; do
  echo "$REPLY" | mail your@email.address
done < <(tail -f /var/log/auth.log | grep --line-buffered login)
```

But this would be running continuously in the background, rather than as a cron job or something.

Comment: This is working great but mail-s are not send, I just got info "You have new mail in /var/mail/root
Any way to fix this?

Comment: You need to set up a mail server or forwarder on your local system, or tell `mail` how to contact your SMTP server of choice. That's a whole different topic though.